# I need make faster barcode reader with zxing and android studio

Tags: java, android, zxing

The only thing I need to work faster at the moment is to read the barcode, but i cant do it. This is my code and actually use

This is the implementation in gradle:

```
implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0') { transitive = false }
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3
```

This its my function

```
ScanOptions scanOptions = new ScanOptions();
     scanOptions.setPrompt("ESCANEANDO CODIGO");
     scanOptions.setBeepEnabled(true);
            scanOptions.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityPortrait.class);
     barLauncher.launch(scanOptions);
```

and use in

```
ActivityResultLauncher <ScanOptions> barLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(), result -> {
    if (result != null) {
        //write the codebar result in txt
```

I have tried other bar readers and I notice that the autofocus of the camera is much faster than my app

Answer (score 0):

Zxing is the old library barecode reader. It reads a barcode too slow and can't read omnidirectional. I recommend to use firebase mlkit barcode reader for better reader

Comment: Thanks last night I applied that library but I wanted to know if there was another equally fast alternative that does not have the legend below "scanned by google"